Take a Python dictionary with values as lists and create a new list of dictionaries each with the initial key and list values
If I have a dictionary with list values:
users = {'first-name': ['Jim', 'John', 'Jane'], 'last-name': ['Boothe', 'Smith', 'Doe'], 'user': ['100', '101', '102']}

How can I create a new list of dictionaries by separating out each index of the initial dictionary lists with the initial key?
By that, I mean, given the initial dictionary above, I would like to create the following:
payload = [{'first-name': 'Jim", 'last-name': 'Boothe', 'user': '100'}, {'first-name': 'John', 'last-name': 'Smith', 'user': '101'}, {'first-name': 'Jane', 'last-name': 'Doe', 'user': '102'} ]

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around looping through each key's value index and turning it into a new dictionary with the initial key.
I have sorted how to get my first dictionary into my new list, just having issues looping through the rest of the indexes.
users = {'first-name': ['Jim', 'John', 'Jane'], 'last-name': ['Boothe', 'Smith', 'Doe'], 'user': ['100', '101', '102']}

for k in users:
    dict[k] = users[k][0]
    payload = [dict]
print(payload)

Output:
[{'user': '100', 'first-name': 'Jim', 'last-name': 'Boothe'}]

But how do I build on this?

You aren't appending to payload; you are creating a new single-item list each time through the loop.

The below 1-liner should work.
users = {'first-name': ['Jim', 'John', 'Jane'], 'last-name': ['Boothe', 'Smith', 'Doe'], 'user': ['100', '101', '102']}
expected_payload = [{'first-name': 'Jim', 'last-name': 'Boothe', 'user': '100'}, {'first-name': 'John', 'last-name': 'Smith', 'user': '101'}, {'first-name': 'Jane', 'last-name': 'Doe', 'user': '102'} ]


payload = [dict(zip(users.keys(), xs)) for xs in zip(*users.values())]

assert payload == expected_payload


Assuming that all lists are always equal in length:
result = [{key: value[i] for key, value in users.items()} for i in range(len(users["first-name"]))]


Great, the end of that is exaclty what I needed. They will in fact always have the same length, thanks! Still learning python and get stuck in my own head sometimes.

@JimBoothe If this answer solved your problem, consider marking it as accepted. Do not thank in comments.
